# Error importing cv2 in python3, Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, anaconda, opencv3.0

I get the following error when importing opencv in python:

```
> python
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: hb_buffer_set_cluster_level
```

The system is Linux debian 4.7.0-1-amd64, stretch. I have created an environment for Python 3 in Anaconda:

```
conda create --name=envPython3 python=3 anaconda
source activate envPython3
```

and then installed OpenCV:

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3
```

It should be installed because

```
conda list | grep cv
```

returns

```
opencv3          3.1.0         py35_0    menpo
```

Everything works fine with Python 2

[May be this post is related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235012/problem-with-gtk-application-s)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

i also had the same issue.  I found an answer that may work for you.  Try

```
source activate envPython3
conda install -c asmeurer pango
python
>>> import cv2
```

Please see this [github link](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/368)

Answer (score 1):

Try again by installing

`conda install -c https//conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv3`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error on python3 .

Though it was working fine, and then it wasn't. Maybe I installed some other package that caused the conflict. 
None of the above solutions worked.

Resolution by uninstalling menpo and installing conda-forge :

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```